# Ninject, how inject a generic Logger<T> by calling LoggerFactory.CreateLogger

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-extensions

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application.

I have initialized my LoggerFactory in a static class which is called from Global.asax

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;
using System.IO;

namespace web
{
    public static class LogConfig
    {
        public static LoggerFactory LoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();

        public static void RegisterLogger()
        {
            LoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().MinimumLevel.Debug().WriteTo.RollingFile(Path.Combine("", "log-{Date}.txt")).CreateLogger();
            LoggerFactory.AddSerilog();
        }
    }
}
```

now I want to use ninject, to inject an instance of ILogger into my constructor...

In my constructor I have:

```
private ILogger<MyTypeController> _logger;

public MyTypeController(ILogger<MyTypeController>) 
{
    // This works fine but I want to inject it
    _logger = LogConfig.LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyTypeController>();
}
```

The above code works, but I want to inject it using ninject... this is what I have tried but does not even compile:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(ILogger<>)).ToProvider(LogConfig.LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<>());
```

Comment: Cross posted here: https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/issues/259

Comment: I would change the question and ask how to inject a logger created as `CreateLogger<T>` into a constructor argument of non-generic interface `ILogger` instead of `ILogger<T>`. Injection of a `ILogger<T>` is just noise to the consumer that can lead to accidental errors when a wrong `T` is specified and it complicates testing.

Comment: Thanks @Steven... I can update the question. Basically I am trying to replicate what happens in MVC Core, in my MVC framework website. In MVC Core, ILoggerFactory and ILogger<T> are both injected into the programme... but here I need to specifically call the create method of LoggerFactory...

Comment: Injecting `ILoggerFactory` and `ILogger<T>` is a terrible idea, and as I see it, the only reason Microsoft is doing this (and promoting it publicly) is because their built-in container lacks the possibility to map a non-generic interface to a generic implementation. In other words they push bad practices because of their own lacking implementation.

Comment: Thanks again @Steven... So what should I do? I basically don't need the logger Factory, I am using Serilog, I just want to initialize Serilog once, in app start and inject it into classes for logging. I thought using LoggerFactory is a goodIdea, becasue I can change the providers... but I am really new to this... I would really appreciate if you give me a little more detail what would be the best approach? I am totally happy to change the approach.

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question; I'm not that experienced with Ninject. There will be others that will be able to help you with that. I can just help with asking the right question :)

Comment: First, correct your sample that you claim works.  You are not even specifying a parameter name.  Second, add the compilation exception that is keeping it from compiling: do not just make reference to it and not provide it.

Comment: @Brett, Create Logger has several overrides, this is correct usage: ILogger<Foo> foo = factory.CreateLogger<Foo>(); If you read my last comment, I said the code for the last example does not even compile, so I am asking for the correct syntax - there is no exception.

Answer (score 9):

I'm doing the following with NLog but it is also likely to work with Ninject:

```
var createLoggerMethod =
    typeof(LoggerFactoryExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(LoggerFactoryExtensions.CreateLogger),
        new[] {typeof(ILoggerFactory)});
kernel.Bind(typeof(ILogger<>)).ToMethod(context =>
{
    var createLoggerGeneric = createLoggerMethod.MakeGenericMethod(context.GenericArguments);
    var logger = createLoggerGeneric.Invoke(null, new []{ loggerFactory });
    return logger;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the comments given by @Steven and also reading his blog on [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org/blog/2016/06/whats-wrong-with-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/), I have realized that injecting a generic logger `ILogger<T>` is not really a good approach.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345161/should-i-take-ilogger-iloggert-iloggerfactory-or-iloggerprovider-for-a-libra/51394689#51394689) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

very simple solution:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions;
using Ninject;

// ...
// register log factory, in case of serilog:
kernel.Bind<ILoggerFactory>().To<SerilogLoggerFactory>();

// register generic ILogger<T>
kernel.Bind(typeof(ILogger<>)).To(typeof(Logger<>));
```